How to retrieve the records with array input?
We have an entity - "CONFIGURATIONS" as below. With below mentioned TS Code block, SQL query is generated. However, 'configuration' remains an empty array after query execution.
If I execute same query in sqldeveloper by replacing ':1' with 'TEST' then records are returned.
Can you please help me to understand what could be the issue.
Entity:
import { Column, Entity, Index, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity({ name: "CONFIGURATIONS" })
export class Configuration {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    name: "ID",
    primaryKeyConstraintName: "configurations_pk",
  })
  id?: number;

  @Column({
    name: "CONFCATEGORY",
    nullable: false,
    type: "varchar2",
    length: 256,
  })
  @Index("configurations_idx1_confcategory")
  confCategory!: string;

  @Column({ name: "CONFID", nullable: true, type: "varchar2", length: 4000 })
  confID!: string;

  @Column({
    name: "CONFLABEL",
    nullable: false,
    type: "varchar2",
    length: 4000,
  })
  confLabel!: string;

  @Column({ name: "CONFVALUE", nullable: false, type: "clob" })
  confValue!: string;

  @Column({
    default: "NO",
    name: "ISACTIVE",
    nullable: false,
    type: "varchar2",
    length: 256,
  })
  isActive!: string;

  @Column({
    name: "CREATEDBY",
    nullable: false,
    type: "varchar2",
    length: 256,
  })
  createdBy?: string;

  @Column({
    default: () =>
      "CAST(systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)",
    name: "CREATIONDATE",
    nullable: false,
    type: "timestamp with time zone",
  })
  creationDate?: Date;

  @Column({
    default: "0.0.0.0",
    name: "SOURCEIP",
    nullable: false,
    type: "varchar2",
    length: 256,
  })
  sourceIP?: string;

  @Column({
    name: "LASTUPDATEDBY",
    nullable: true,
    type: "varchar2",
    length: 256,
  })
  lastUpdatedBy?: string;

  @Column({
    name: "LASTUPDATEDDATE",
    nullable: true,
    type: "timestamp with time zone",
  })
  lastUpdatedDate?: Date;
}

TS Code:
if (datasource.isInitialized) {
    const configurations: Configuration[] = await datasource
      .getRepository(Configuration)
      .createQueryBuilder("configuration")
      .where(`"configuration"."CONFCATEGORY" IN (:...categories)`, {
        categories: confCategory,
      })
      .select([
        `"configuration"."CONFCATEGORY"`,
        `"configuration"."CONFID"`,
        `"configuration"."CONFLABEL"`,
        `"configuration"."CONFVALUE"`,
        `"configuration"."ISACTIVE"`,
      ])
      .orderBy(`"configuration".CONFCATEGORY`, "ASC")
      .getMany();

      response.configurations = {...configurations}
      response.totalRecords = configurations.length;
}

SQL Query:
SELECT "configuration"."CONFCATEGORY", "configuration"."CONFID", "configuration"."CONFLABEL", "configuration"."CONFVALUE", "configuration"."ISACTIVE" FROM "CONFIGURATIONS" "configuration" WHERE "configuration"."CONFCATEGORY" IN (:1) ORDER BY "configuration".CONFCATEGORY ASC -- PARAMETERS: ["TEST"]


SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4);

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
